# При регистрации пользователя не происходит вызов действия signup методом post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть следующая форма регистрации:

**view authorization/signup**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Authorization", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-md-2 padding0 feedback">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="InputFIO">Фамилия</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputFIO", placeholder = "Зареченская", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="InputName">Имя</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputName", placeholder = "Анна", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="InputSecondName">Отчество</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputSecondName", placeholder = "Ивановна", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="InputDate">Дата рождения</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Birthday, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputDate", placeholder = "22.04.1959", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="radio1">
            <p>Пол</p>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, Gender.Male, new { name = "rbtnGender", id = "optionsRadios2" })
            <label><span class="cbxGender"></span> Мужской</label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, Gender.Female, new { name = "rbtnGender", id = "optionsRadios1" })
            <label><span class="cbxGender"></span>Женский</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5 padding0">
            <label for="weight">Рост (см.)</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Growth, new { @class = "form-control", id = "weight", placeholder = "176", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 padding0">
            <label for="height">Вес (кг.)</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Weight, new { @class = "form-control", id = "height", placeholder = "69", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="country">Страна проживания</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, ViewBag.Countries as SelectList, "Выберите страну", new { @class = "form-control", id = "country", type = "text", placeholder = "Россия" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="city">Город</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CityId, ViewBag.Cities as SelectList, "Выберите город", new { @class = "form-control", id = "city", type = "text", placeholder = "Москва" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="telephone">Телефон</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone, new { @class = "form-control", id = "telephone", placeholder = "+7 949 545-55-55", type = "text" })
            <span><img src="~/Content/img/info.png" />для оперативной связи</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="email">Эл. почта</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new {@class = "form-control", id = "email", placeholder = "ekaterina@mail.com", type = "text"})
            <span><img src="~/Content/img/error.png" />Эл. почта не введена</span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password">Пароль</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control", id = "password", type = "password" })
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="confirmPassword">Повторите пароль</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", id = "confirmPassword", type = "password" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="checkbox1 col-md-8 padding0">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
        <label><span class="cbxUserAgreement"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Пользовательским соглашением</a></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
        <label><span class="cbxRegulationsPersonalData"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Положением о персональных данных</a> </label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
        <label><span class="cbxLimitationPprofessionalLiability"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Ограничением профессиональной ответственности</a> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send">Зарегистрироваться</button>
}
```

Ввожу все данные, нажимаю кнопку, но вызов экшена signup не происходит. Грузится страница и дальше никакого результата. Поставил точку останова в экшене, почему-то отладчик не заходит в данный метод. Собственно вот сам action:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("SignUp")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SignUpPost(SignUpModel model)
{
    SelectList tempList;

    // 1 - Валидация
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // 2 - Проверяем на дублирование почты пользователя
        User user = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(x => x.Email.Equals(model.Email) && !x.IsDeleted).SingleOrDefault();

        if (user != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("user", "Пользователь с таким адресом электронной почты уже зарегистрирован.");
            model.Password = string.Empty;
            model.ConfirmPassword = string.Empty;
            tempList = GetCountrySelectList();
            ViewBag.Countries = tempList;
            ViewBag.Cities = GetCitiesSelectList(Int32.Parse(tempList.First().Value));

            return View(model);
        }

        // 3 - Валидация дня рождения
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (model.Birthday < currentDate.AddYears(-100) || model.Birthday > currentDate.AddYears(-16))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("model.Birthday", "Допустимый возраст пользователей от 16 и старше.");
            model.Password = string.Empty;
            model.ConfirmPassword = string.Empty;
            tempList = GetCountrySelectList();
            ViewBag.Countries = tempList;
            ViewBag.Cities = GetCitiesSelectList(Int32.Parse(tempList.First().Value));

            return View(model);
        }

        // 4 - Шифруем пароль
        String hashedPassword = CryptographyHelper.HashPassword(model.Password);

        // 5 - Генерируем ключ активации
        String activationToken = CryptographyHelper.GenerateActivationToken();

        // 6 - Создаем пользователя и сохраняем его в БД
        User dataUser = new User
        {
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            MiddleName = model.MiddleName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            CountryId = model.CountryId,
            CityId = model.CityId,
            Birthday = model.Birthday,
            CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Email = model.Email,
            ConfirmationToken = activationToken,
            UserPasswordHash = hashedPassword,
            Gender = (int)model.Gender,
            Growth = model.Growth,
            Weight = model.Weight,
            IsDeleted = false,
            LastVisitDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Phone = model.Phone
        };
        _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(dataUser);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();

        // 7 - Отправляем письмо для подтверждения регистрации
        if (HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
        {
            ConfirmRegistrationMailMessage mailMessage =
                        new ConfirmRegistrationMailMessage(dataUser, HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            await Emailer.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("RegistrationSuccess");
    }

    tempList = GetCountrySelectList();
    ViewBag.Countries = tempList;
    ViewBag.Cities = GetCitiesSelectList(Int32.Parse(tempList.First().Value));

    model.Password = string.Empty;
    model.ConfirmPassword = string.Empty;
    return View(model);
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в данной проблеме. Спасибо.

Comment: Проверяйте консоль браузера - убедитесь что хоть какой-то запрос уходит на сервер. Если не уходит - значит срабатывают клиентские валидаторы - проверяйте атрибуты обязательности на полях (или просто уберите их, для поиска проблемы)

Comment: Спасибо. Может вопрос совсем глупый, но как в гугл хром поверить, какой запрос уходит на сервер?

Comment: можно воспользоваться отладкой, *F12* - вроде

Answer (score 1):

я попробовал у себя запустить ваш код и вот результаты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

model:

```
 public class SignUpModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

}
```

view:

```
    @model Models.SignUpModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SignUpPost";
}

<h2>SignUpPost</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-md-2 padding0 feedback">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="InputFIO">Фамилия</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputFIO", placeholder = "Зареченская", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="InputName">Имя</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputName", placeholder = "Анна", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="InputSecondName">Отчество</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputSecondName", placeholder = "Ивановна", type = "text" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
            <label for="InputDate">Дата рождения</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Birthday, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputDate", placeholder = "22.04.1959", type = "text" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="checkbox1 col-md-8 padding0">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
        <label><span class="cbxUserAgreement"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Пользовательским соглашением</a></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
        <label><span class="cbxRegulationsPersonalData"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Положением о персональных данных</a> </label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
        <label><span class="cbxLimitationPprofessionalLiability"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Ограничением профессиональной ответственности</a> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send">Зарегистрироваться</button>
}
```

actions:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SignUpPost()
{

    return View();
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("SignUp")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SignUpPost(SignUpModel model)
{

    return View(model);
}
```

думаю вы не создали вью как строго типизированный.